# Period as abbreviation and bullet point usages

Tags: punctuation, periods

Usage questions surrounding period (.)

1. Plural after abbreviation do you add s?

   e.g. certificates->cert.s, environments->env.s, configurations->config.s?
2. as bullet points period or bracket goes first?

   e.g. i.) or ii).?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Wikipedia--Hart's Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation#Plural_forms)

> When an abbreviation contains more than one full point, Hart's Rules recommends putting the s after the final one.
>
> Ph.D.s
>
> M.Phil.s
>
> the d.t.s

2. This is subjective; there's no formal rule for how a bullet point should look

Comment: Great! Thanks. Ok, what about there is just one period, like my examples?

Comment: @user1589188 ~ same thing I would imagine